# How to keep color quality with imagick

Tags: php, pdf, imagick

I am toying with Imagick in PHP8 and facing some issues. My first goal was to center a picture inside a SVG. In the end, I put the picture inside an image tag of the svg, then converting the whole SVG into a PNG and put that PNG inside a PDF file.

When applying the picture inside a PDF, the colors are a bit off in some PDF readers (like Adobe's), like "washed out". In some readers, like PSPDFKit's js viewer, it is normal.

This is how my image is supposed to look (orange bar on the left being the SVG) :

[image: original]

When passing it through imagick, the picture looks "washed out" :

[image: washed out image]

My code, very basic :

```
    $imagick->readImageBlob($svg);
    $imagick->setImageFormat('png');
    $png = $imagick->getImageBlob();
```

I tried mostly to see if opacity/transparency was responsible, also tried other image formats (other types of PNG seen [here](https://imagemagick.org/script/formats.php))

EDIT : It seems the issue comes from the picture generation, as just putting the picture inside the PDF (without converting it in a first place) doesn't affect its quality. The PDF is generated by another program I don't have the hand over.

Comment: I think this might be a [color profile issue](https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.profileimage.php). Your question is somewhat unclear. Does the color difference show up when you convert the SVG to PNG, or when the PNG is included in the PDF? In other words, where's the problem exactly? How do you generate the PDF?

Comment: Editing the post to clarify according to your comment :), will look into those color profile.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with PNG format. I tried in JPG and GIF, colors are normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the issue by switching my picture format to jpg instead of png. Considering my usecase, I won't be affected by the loss of transparency nor the lossy compression.

So basically :

```
$imagick->readImageBlob($svg);
$imagick->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$png = $imagick->getImageBlob();
```